# Is this Group by hours formula?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

**N** - the number of hours to be grouped

**DATETIME column** value (eg, 2011-10-08 21:23:43)

Note: for Mysql DB

```
GROUP BY date( `DATETIME` ) , N* floor( date_format( `DATETIME` , '%H' ) /N ))
```

1. Is this Group by hours formula?
2. Any formula for group by day/month?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTH(dt) as m, DAY(dt) as d, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (
SELECT '2011-10-11 10:00:00' as dt
UNION ALL
SELECT '2011-10-11 20:00:00' as dt
UNION ALL
SELECT '2011-10-12 10:00:00' as dt
UNION ALL
SELECT '2011-10-12 20:00:00' as dt
UNION ALL
SELECT '2011-10-13 10:00:00' as dt
UNION ALL
SELECT '2011-10-13 20:00:00' as dt
UNION ALL
SELECT '2011-11-13 10:00:00' as dt
UNION ALL
SELECT '2011-11-13 20:00:00' as dt
) as dates
GROUP BY m, d;
```

results in:

```
+------+------+-----+
| m    | d    | cnt |
+------+------+-----+
|   10 |   11 |   2 |
|   10 |   12 |   2 |
|   10 |   13 |   2 |
|   11 |   13 |   2 |
+------+------+-----+
```